# Autobahn, leave onMessage block

Tags: python, websocket, autobahn

I have an autobahn Websocket Server with the typical `onX` functions in it's protocol. My problem is that I can't find a way to exit `onX`, while keep doing the various stuff that I wanted to do when the specific message arrived. More specifically in my `onMessage` function, I sometimes perform an HTTP request to an API which is very slow. As a result, the client that sent the websocket message is being blocked by the server's `onMessage` finalization. Even if I do `self.sendMessage` or `reactor.callFromThread(<http request here>)`, or `self.transport.loseConnection()` from the server side, in the `onMessage` block, the `onMessage` is still executing the HTTP request and my client waits.

This is my client's code:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def send(command,userPath,token):
    websocket = yield from websockets.connect('wss://127.0.0.1:7000',ssl=ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2))
    data = json.dumps({"api_command":"session","body":command,"headers": {'X-User-Path': userPath, 'X-User-Token': token}})
    response = {}
    try:
        yield from websocket.send(data)
    finally:
        yield from websocket.close()
    if 'command' in response:
        if response['command'] == 'ACK_SESSION_COMMAND' or response['command'] == 'ACK_INITIALIZATION':
            return ('OK',200)
        else:
            return('',400)
```

I even tried to just `websocket.send(data)`, from the client, but for some reason it doesn't send the data (I don't see them arriving in the server). I don't understand how can I return from the `onMessage` block and keep doing my HTTP request.

And to explain my situation, I just want to sent 1 ssl websocket message to my server and immediately close the connection. Anything that can do that, suits me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reactor.callInThread` instead of `reactor.callFromThread`, causes the application flow to release and the HTTP request is performed independently in a thread. As described in the twisted documentation : http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/threading.html